# C# Windows notifications on webmail browser control

Tags: c#, geckofx

I'm looking for a possible solution to an issue im having with making my C# Helpdesk Application (Windows Forms App)  to display a Windows Notification when a new email comes in on the Web Browser loaded to the user's webmail.

Our current application has a tab control in which 1 of those tabs are "Email" within that tab  is a GeckoFX browser loading the webmail portal from Zoho.

I'm very new at code & building apps in general and just starting out in C# so I'm looking for possible resources or answers on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: You want to detect a change in the HTML shown by GeckoFX?

Comment: I would say so, basically the GeckoFX with the email loaded is generally sitting on the inbox so the change for a new email coming through is where I'd like to see the notification on. We currently use the webmail in chrome, the Google Chrome browser shows 1 new mail notification when an email comes in but our GeckoFX has not. I've looked into examples for this but came back empty I guess I am not too sure what I should be looking for as this aspect of C# "Windows Notifications" is new to me.